# How to change view-assigned data before render in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware

**Laravel related question**

For the following SomeController class, I am returning view with "data". I want to search if the assigned "data" has an "id" column and encrypt it before rendering the view. So when I access "data" from the view file, "id" is encrypted.

```
class SomeController 
{
    public function index(): View
    {
        $data = array(
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'siam'
        );
        return view('Views/View/Index', compact('data'));
    }
}
```

Maybe it is possible to extend View class and encrypt in the extended class method. But I was hoping to get it done without extending View class.

- Idea

a. Using middleware

Can I use middleware handler that triggers before rendering View?

b. Any other ways

Or any other ways using which I can modify view-assigned data before render View.

Thank you everyone in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When rendering a `View`, Laravel will dispatch a [`composing:<view-name>`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/View/Concerns/ManagesEvents.php#L179) event. You could hook into this event by creating a generic `ViewComposer` as follows:

```
View::composer('*', function ($view) {
    if ($view->id && is_int($view->id)) {
        $view->id = encrypt($view->id);
    }
});
```

See the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#view-composers) on ViewComposers for more information.